# How do I set up a domain name to SSH into my webserver?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, dns, webserver

I'm running a webserver (running Ubuntu 16.04) in my mother's front room that I'll be using to host sites for the two of us. I'm moving out next week so I'll be managing it remotely.

I have set up my current websites with dynu.com for Dynamic DNS so that the DNS records will change when the dynamic IP on the home router changes. However, I would like to set up a domain name for the server itself, solely to be used when connecting to it via SSH, so I can type ssh user@myservername.com rather than ssh user@123.234.210.123. Is there an easy way to do this, or would it involve setting up my own DNS server?

Comment: Hey Michael! If it is just for type preference, would editing the `hosts` file be discouraged here? You could attribute the naming you'd desire without having to actually configure further systems. Would also only work on the computer with the edited `hosts` file. If you wish to be able to use that naming anywhere though, then forget my proposition

Comment: You could use tools like [No IP](https://www.noip.com/free?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIntGaie3-4AIVmYXVCh2isQY0EAAYASAAEgJ-UvD_BwE&utm_campaign=free-dynamic-dns&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=adwords&utm_term=free-dynamic-dns) to help you have a free domain and an up to date ip from your home as well. What do you recon? :)

Comment: Hey Diego, I can actually set up dynamic DNS updating from my Netgear router with No-IP (I didn't go with it for my actual websites as I wanted more than 3 and dynu.com was was cheaper).

But how do I actually set up a domain name for SSH in the Ubuntu side of things? Just edit the hosts file?

Comment: Thank you for sharing that @Michael! Whenever I do not wish to type ips and prefer a significant explicit word, I set that in my `/etc/hosts` file. Lets say I want to connect to 92.13.5.1 but dont want to keep remembering or typing the ip, I just go to `/etc/hosts` and add it as `<ip> test-server` for example, and can then connect using `ssh <user>@test-server` instead of the ip per say. But I am a bit confused if such would be a solution you wish or looking for DNS because you can be trying to access from many different computers. Editing `/etc/hosts` is like a personal singular pc "solution"

Comment: I have a feeling you are actually looking on creating a DNS service? If so, I apologise as what I am referring is not what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

as long as you use dyndns (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/dyndns.1.html) correctly there's no need to additionally setup anything and you will be able to connect to the hostname via domain name. I had this running with my own domain some time ago and it worked fine every time the router IP changed. You could just use the domain name then, since it was already updated on the DNS side.